# Pregunta sobre Parse Error

Tags: php

Hice la corrección sugerida por GBianchi pero sigue el mismo error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'DB_PASSWORD' (T_STRING) in /home1/pesosalu/public_html/wp-config.php on line 30

Y el wp-config-php quedó así, ya con la corrección hecha.

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'pesosalu_Rajan');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'XXXXXXXXXX');


/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXXXXX');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY', 'TD!dGH+)qz|(GjKNjLe;ut}O}UZg$N{o]|sVKO*=VBNVCOIAjBjFFnDDJEkVydTWQEaRLelOF!BueM]mRHd$$MhEzJ/$_ufXz(k[BVi%f@!mTRGT<ccZdS[DyAU{zcJy');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY', 'CN^n[awgcXgy)vPo=DJ%/bg*Z(d|MAR]baZ(f%*mLAD|dLcPptMT<+Yqi%WX/nz_wDF/MQk[gmjLghfo]+uNZgk)pf+By(*lNQkLDuqzgRWG[sPq(uXPPUaj+ui@P(K<');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY', 'laaE]Rv-H-BE?Z$tK+VzT@=fZ<a-qEG_l}x*I{h(Thwhm^FdScRT[)c<tW<oVZ?;twRE/j%GTh*;h=s+MFSj/>{GNSpdsyAPx)@)xTUgG&sBcOhqgw^TDM_Vc%yn/}!m');
define('NONCE_KEY', 'fsCwQRG?LccMLO(=glSr/TlaP(k/]GtGup-sk_Br?pY/{?>p=t<(HlhaEQtHzj]zt^[+CFmOt@)c-*OSZ?&+sJ/K-S[Ic(WCcTB<dTTbeKar]xpNf{$JvWXgpbyM&qUJ');
define('AUTH_SALT', '_{f!^W_)opG(+I[To=eW/|PLvY?o<!ehPh!|VCCqmqJyWplbbxGcllXJ<SyjV]LRV?c=$(Y$Iyer+MjY{](YHjczCldrAhcoc/g$BVHridwd@a}ul(ZVdXbEgwopSysb');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'TZdB[J^<rtof/]]MZsHm_-X!SWQvpPRTxb<o_<RZY]lw!?mpEmdg/xOMz;]A{ITG/{+ZeOni)_)FTAuI!oGrX*gpYjqcIr!/<{KyFC+IA]((Ehx=dH?wqqh{?v)WIA^b');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT', 'k-@npXBDmQdx?oBjAO!o<DE)cU]{P*K$$A}$}x{XNi}/NUhMa}&qcCoJce+nEo%v*MCPveAwI?GQjBV/z!K-xR=DR{DX<oL|>;?%qMgbU-!%PgDGJqxIq!Sqmn$^/a-z');
define('NONCE_SALT', '(>up<}C*ia/EXvSpr$rpu(<P$oC->{K|yP>y^$GFMV<$l]!i^E-/Kpu%Ps$$nievsf$Kw!+Rdw/ELo+rRzvJP*%Lm)]U;dToUzdqfEvCIhhGUd^Ri-?ogaHgucl{es_/');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_zvcu_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG',false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: no sobra un '); antes de definir el password?

Comment: Quiere decir que debo eliminar

Comment: Perdón quiere decir que debo eliminar /** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'XXXXXXXXX');
');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXXX');

Comment: Entonces debo eliminar esto '); que está encima de DB Password y abajo de DB User?

Comment: ya eliminé '); pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, esto no solucionó el problema

Comment: vas a tener que editar la pregunta y volver a poner el archivo de vuelta, a ver si tenes algun otro error

Comment: Has editado la pregunta, has puesto el "nuevo" código... que tiene el mismo error que @gbianchi te dijo que corrigieras porque no has cambiado el código en nada.

Answer (score 1):

');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXXX');

como dice gbianchi te esta tomando

> ');
>
> /** MySQL database password */ define('

como texto antes del DB_PASSWORD Y por eso el error

Comment: ya elimine '); pero sigue el error

Comment: el segundo error que te dice luego de eliminarla_?